# Using classList when element is set to display none

Tags: javascript, css

i want to use javascript to toggle between classes. i cant figure out why it is that an element that is set to `display: none;` can not receive a class using classList.

in other words, if i say

```
    #div1{

        width: 25%;
        background-color: #000000;
        display: none;

    }

  #div2{

        width: 50%;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: #cccccc;


    }

    .fullview{

           width: 99%;
           height: 500px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           border: 1px solid #000000;


    }
```

with

```
<div  id="div1">
content here
</div>

<div  onclick="myFunction()" id="div2">
content here
</div>

<script>


function myFunction() {
         document.getElementById("div1").classList.toggle("fullview");
}
</script>
```

it wont give `div1` the `fullview`class

but if i switch it around and take `display:none;` away from `div1` and put it on the `fullview`class the script works just fine. but i DONT want div1 to be visible or to reserve space until div2 is clicked

is this because the script has run before the div has been "created"??

what alternatives do i have??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about specificity in CSS, ID's are more specific than classes, so even if your element gets the class, the styles aren't specific enough.

Change the style to include the ID, and of course, if you want to see the change, make the element visible

```
#div1.fullview{

       width: 99%;
       height: 500px;
       border-radius: 5px;
       border: 1px solid #000000;
       display : block

}
```

```css
#div1 {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: none;
}

#div2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

#div1.fullview {
    width: 99%;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    content here
</div>

<div onclick="myFunction()" id="div2">
    content here
</div>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("div1").classList.toggle("fullview");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: i actually changed the div id's for the sake of the examples but yes they are still similar in that manner. ill change them and make them more specific.